# Using php exception for api login error

Tags: php, exception

I have the following login controller :-

```
  public function doLogin(Request $request)
    {

        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://domainname/api/v1/']);
         $r = $client->request('POST', 'login', [
            'form_params' => [
                'username' => $request->username,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'platform' => 'web'
            ]
        ]);


        if ($r->getStatusCode() !== '200') {
            return back()->with('errors','Invalid User Name or password');
        }
}
```

If the credential is wrong, error page is showing

ClientException in RequestException.php line 113:
Client error: `POST https://domainname/api/v1/login` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"error":"invalid_credentials"}

How can i use the php exception (Try and catch) for the above code.

Comment: Please review the documentation to how to use try/catch/finally blocks http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`try/catch` blocks are pretty simple. You need to wrap the code that will throw the exception in the `try` block, and catch the thrown exception type in the `catch` block.

It wasn't clear from your question whether a `ClientException` or `RequestException` was being thrown, so I've typehinted the `catch` block with a generic `Exception`. You can tighten this up by type hinting it with the appropriate `Exception` class.

```
use Exception;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

public function doLogin(Request $request)
{
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://domainname/api/v1/']);

    try {
        $response = $client->request('POST', 'login', [
            'form_params' => [
                'username' => $request->username,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'platform' => 'web',
            ],
        ]);
    }
    catch (Exception $exception) {
        return back()->with('errors', 'Invalid username and/or password');
    }

    // Your code for a successful login
}
```

Comment: It worked, i have included "use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;"